# Vertical alignment of inline elements and remove space between from inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

I have made some problem to solve. For example, I have two blocks with constant width and `display: inline-block` (http://jsfiddle.net/mgs8jLwk/). How can I force left one to stay at top? Sorry if it is duplicate of some question.

P.S. Is there any way to make two or more columns without commenting spaces in html markup?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/mgs8jLwk/4/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For Question 1 - Make Blocks Align Top:

Use "`vertical-align:top;`" for "`#one`" div.

```
#one {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    vertical-align:top; /*FIX ADDED*/
}
```

#### For Question 2 - Alternate of `<!-- COMMENT-->` to Remove Space Between DIVS :

Add "`font-size:0;`" to the parent element:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    font-size:0;
}
```

Here are few more options to get rid of the space between inline-block elements: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

### **Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8cfmjzg9/**

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 2):

Add `vertical-align: top` to your CSS rule for `#one`:

```
#one
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mgs8jLwk/1/

Comment: It does if you move the `<!-- -->` comment between the divs as you did from the OP fiddle to yours.

Comment: Why rely on a hack for this when you can float them and not worry about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can float them both left:

```
#one, #two {
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/m72qrsa6/)**